# Using Variables to access controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I am trying to reference some text boxes in VB.NET using variable names, like

```
Me.Controls("myfield" & xx).Text = "some text"
```

However I keep getting errors and can't seem to work out how to reference the controls correctly this way. Any help would be most appreciated.

Have tried other solutions found within this site, such as searching for the field first and then trying to populate it, but still get errors.

The error I am getting is

> *System.NullReferenceException 'object reference not set to an instance
> of an object'*

Comment: Discovered that because the controls are in a group box, you have to reference the group box first, then the control. Like me.groupboxname.controls("myfield" & (xx).tostring).Text = "Some Text"

Comment: Since `GroupBox` is a container control, its child controls are not exposed directly in the `Form`. You should iterate the controls of the `GroupBox` separately.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that because the controls are in a group box, you have to reference the group box first, then the control. Like me.groupboxname.controls("myfield" & (xx).tostring).Text = "Some Text"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).